# Is there a name for numbers that have 2 as their greatest common divisor?

Tags: terminology, factoring

Is there a name for numbers that have `two` as their greatest common divisor? Such as 8 and 130.

Comment: These are numbers of the form $2m$ and $2n$ with $m,n$ coprime. Not really a name.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a name for numbers that have two as their greatest common divisor? Such as 8 and 130.

No.

They are just “*numbers with a greatest common divisor of 2*”.  There is no succinct name for this.